# Not Showing Embeded youtube video in email template

Tags: html, email, youtube

Is it possible to embed video into an email that will allow the viewer to watch the video within the email itself?

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wbY_Szw8X7Q" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I use above iframe code in my email template instead of the video it showing blank.

Comment: No, in short it's not possible. You need to provide a link to either the video source, or a downloadable mp4 inside the email as an attachment

Comment: FYI, due to spam and security reasons, embedded videos are not supported in email across most major email clients, such as Gmail and Outlook. Even though if its possible, it doesn't seem to be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, unfortunately, is that it's not possible. You need to:

- Provide a link to the video source (in your case `https://www.youtube.com/embed/wbY_Szw8X7Q`)
- Attach this file as an mp4 to the email itself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the E-mail provider. Each provider supports different "HTML E-mails". Some support iframes, others don't. I would encourage you to Google which E-mail providers support iframes, and which don't.

Some pointers:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/08/do-iframes-work-in-email/

https://www.simplycast.com/interactive-marketing-support/faqs/are-iframes-compatible-with-emails/

https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21773969/IFRAME-in-a-mail-possible.html

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

You must not embed a video because it is not supported by major [email clients](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/embed-video-in-email).  You may however show a thumbnail image, with a link.  Once they click on on the thumbnail "play button", it redirects to the link URL, and plays the video, in a browser.